# Birt Report strange response time behaviour

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, memory-management, birt

I am using Birt Report to generate transactional reports in PDF format. Currently, the service receives approximately 50 requests per minute. The problem is that over time, the response times and PDF generation speed start to decrease, as can be seen in the graph:

[image]

Initially, I thought it might be a problem with heap memory usage, but I don't see the same pattern there:

[image]

I do see a similar pattern in non-heap memory usage.

[image]

Where should I start looking for the problem? I don't know much about non-heap memory usage, and I'm not sure if this is the issue

Comment: Oddly, it's more likely your GC scheme if you have one, the memory will fill but it won't clean out it's dump space until it is critical to it. You need to put in a GC scheme probably.      https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html      https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/set-heapmemory-jvm-arguments-tomcat/

Comment: The response is heavily depending on the way you are processing parallel requests. Noby can answer this without more details. A wild guess: Your are processing all reports one after the other in some way (not in a parallel fashion), so if e.g. you have 1 request per second and report generation takes 1.5 secs, then for the first report there is a response time of 1.5 secs, 2 secs for the second report, 2.5 for the 3rd report and so on.